# what is current path in 6 winding transformer

Tags: current, transformer

The 6 winding transformer which i shown in figure is a 1:1:1:1:1:1 transformer.It is a schematic of wurth electronics flex transformer. If I apply voltage at one winding of primary what is the current path in secondary? and what is the applications of this type of 6 winding and equal ratio transformers?[image]

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you?

Comment: These transformers are usually made to be configured the way you want. Here, you can put the windings in series to get 1:1, 1:2, 1:3, 2:3, 3:2, 2:1, or 3:1. You could also configure it to have multiple secondaries.

Comment: data sheet giving the information about only electrical properties like inductance, rated current, leakage inductance, temperature body dimensions and drawings only.If you want to check the part number in wurth electronik is 749196101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is meant to be a flexible transformer that can do many things, depending on how you connect the windings.  Each winding is magnetically coupled to the others.  It is up to you how to connect windings in series or parallel or leave them open to get the ratios you want.

Secondary windings connected in series give you higher voltage at the same current.  In parallel, they give you higher current at the same voltage.  For primary windings, they have the opposite effect.

The advantage of a device like this is that you can stock one transformer and use it for different purposes in different designs.  It also helps the manufacturer in that they don't have to make as many different transformers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a current transformer, if you apply an AC voltage to one winding, you can measure nearly the same voltage at all other windings. Current flows only through windings connected to a load. You can use only two windings or more. You may connect several windings in series or parallel, but you have to respect the winding direction. The dots are marking the winding direction. For a parallel connection, pin 1 may be connected to pin 2 and pin 4 to pin 5. For a serial connection, pin 4 and 2 are connected. The parallel connection is used for more current and less windings resistance, the serial connection for more voltage and higher resistance. You can use this transformer for a 1:1 ratio, but also 1:2, 1:3, 1:4, 1:5, 2:3.

Comment: So if i apply voltage at one winding at primary, current will flows in all windings in secondary?

Comment: Current will be _available_ in all windings, but will only flow if a load is connected to that winding.

Comment: If you apply a voltage to one primary winding, a voltage will be available at all other secondary windings. If you connect a load to a secondary winding, a current will flow. Current cant flow through a secondary winding alone, current will flow only in a closed circuit. The winding alone is an open circuit without a current flow.